# How to Combine lines of the file in linux?

Tags: linux, file

I Currently have a file in below format

```
state  :  CONNECTED ,
state  :  CONNECTED ,
state  :  CONNECTED ,
Rno  :  5554f1d2-6f1b
Rno  :  10587563-4181
Rno  :  be6312f7-b4df
```

I want it to be in below format , how do we do this using linux commands ?

```
state : CONNECTED ,Rno : 5554f1d2
state : CONNECTED ,Rno : 10587563
state : CONNECTED ,Rno : be6312f7
```

Note : Spaces after state and : should also be removed .

Comment: Sorry it should be 
a:1
b:2
A:1
B:2
and i wnat it to be like 
a:1;A=1;
b=2:B=2;

Comment: Any little script can do this. Where are you having a problem, and what are you using? Also which OS?

Comment: its like we have a and b one below the other and A and B below a and b .
now i want it to b like a and A to be in one line and b and B to be in one line.

Comment: I am getting the above Output which is in the question in the script itself by making one command and redirecting it to textfile.
Now in the script itself i wnat to use some commands so that i can get the desired result.

Comment: Linux OS .
After getting the output in desired format i am going to fetch respective Rno if state is disconnected .

Comment: If your first two comments ("Sorry it should be") and ("its like we have") are still valid, you should correct the main text of your Q and delete the comments. Also, you should indicate if 3 lines of combining is the absolute requirement, or can it be N lines of combining. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input file as

A 1
B 2
a 1
b 2 
C 1
 and you want 
A 1 a 1 C 1 
B 2 b 2

your command could be like 
`awk '{a[$2]=a[$2]" "$0;}END{for(x in a){print a[x]}}'`

or if you require output like

A 1 a 1
B 2 b 2
C 1

your command could be like 
`awk '{a[toupper($1)]=a[toupper($1)]" "$0;}END{for(x in a){print a[x]}}'`